# Recursion - Java

Tags: java, recursion

I am working on a program where I have to use [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) to calculate the sum of 1/3 + 2/5 + 3/7 + 4/9 + ... + i / (2i + 1).  However, I am not sure how to make my program show the term that must be added in order to reach the number enter by the user. For example. If I enter 12, I want to know how many terms of the series [1/3 + 2/5 + 3/7 + 4/9 + ... + i / (2i + 1)] were added to get approximately to the number 12.

What I don't want to get is the sum of inputting 12 which in this case is 5.034490247342584 rather I want to get the term that if I were to sum all numbers up to that term I would get something close to 12.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

This is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Recursion {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double number;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a value=  ");
    number = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println(sum(number) + " is the  term that should be added in order to reach " + number);

}

public static double sum(double k) {
    if (k == 1) 
        return 1/3;
    else 
        return ((k/(2*k+1))+ sum(k-1));
     }  
}
```

Comment: why is your `sum` function treating `k` as the *number of terms to add* if you want it to be treated as *the limit of the sum of a sequence*?

Comment: You have this question kind of inside out.  If you want to know how many terms you need to add to get to 12, you'll have to *reverse* your algorithm.  Keep adding successive k / (2k + 1) for larger and larger k until you hit your desired target.  With your current sum method, you would have to start guessing at starting values of k and perform a sort of "binary search" for an acceptably close solution.

Comment: ... Why do you want to know how many iterations it would take? Just check for a value close to the desired value with a known delta. Then you know how many iterations it takes.

Comment: "_[...] where I have to use recursion_" Why do you have to use recursion? In your case a `while` loop seems more appropriate to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this problem should be solved using recursion, but... if you need to implement it on that way, this is a possible solution:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Recursion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double number;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a value=  ");
        number = input.nextInt();

        double result = 0;
        double expectedValue = number;

        int k = 0;
        while (result < expectedValue) {
            k++;
            result = sum(k);
        }

        System.out.println(k
                + " is the  term that should be added in order to reach "
                + number + " (" + sum(k) + ")");

    }

    public static double sum(double k) {
        if (k == 1)
            return 1 / 3;
        else
            return ((k / (2 * k + 1)) + sum(k - 1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have this question kind of inside out. If you want to know how many terms you need to add to get to 12, you'll have to *reverse* your algorithm. Keep adding successive k / (2k + 1) for larger and larger k until you hit your desired target. With your current sum method, you would have to start guessing at starting values of k and perform a sort of "binary search" for an acceptably close solution.