# How to loop a certain area of code after a wrong user input? (Java)

Tags: java

I have been working on a small Rock Paper Scissors game with Java, where the win or lose condition is based on whether the computer or the player wins five games. I am not sure how to get the program to loop at the user input should there be a wrong input.

Here is the code where I'm having this trouble

The section that I'm trying to loop is the portion with "else if (determination.equals("Y")) {"

```
import java.util.*;

public class Rock_Paper_Scissors {

  public static void main(String arg[]) {
    boolean loopGameStart = true;

    while (loopGameStart) {
      System.out.println("Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors, a game programmed "
                       + "by Daniel Park. Would you like to start? (Y/N)");
      Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
      String determination = userInput.next();

      if (determination.equals("N")) {
        System.out.println("Please, do reconsider...");
        loopGameStart = true;
      } else if (determination.equals("Y")) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int n = rand.nextInt(3) + 1;
        // 1 = Rock, 2 = Paper, 3= Scissor
        int humanWinCount = humanWinCount();
        int computerWinCount = computerWinCount();
        System.out.println("Choose 0, 1, or 2 (Rock/Paper/Scissor)");
        Scanner userRPS = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choiceRPS = userRPS.nextInt();
        while ((humanWinCount < 5) && (computerWinCount < 5)) {
          if (choiceRPS == 0) {
            if (n == 1) {
              System.out.println("TIE!!");
              System.out.println("Choose 0, 1, or 2 again (Rock/Paper/Scissor)");
              System.out.println("Computer: " + computerWinCount + " rounds won");
              System.out.println("You: " + humanWinCount + " rounds won");
              choiceRPS = userRPS.nextInt();
            } else if (n == 2) {
              System.out.println("LOSS!!");
              System.out.println("Choose 0, 1, or 2 again (Rock/Paper/Scissor)");
              computerWinCount = computerWinCount + 1;
              System.out.println("Computer: " + computerWinCount + " rounds won");
              System.out.println("You: " + humanWinCount + " rounds won");
              choiceRPS = userRPS.nextInt();
            } else if (n == 3) {
              System.out.println("WIN!!");
              System.out.println("Choose 0, 1, or 2 again (Rock/Paper/Scissor)");
              humanWinCount = humanWinCount + 1;
              System.out.println("Computer: " + computerWinCount + " rounds won");
              System.out.println("You: " + humanWinCount + " rounds won");
              choiceRPS = userRPS.nextInt();
            } else {
              System.out.println("I do not understand... Try Again.");
              System.out.println("Choose 0, 1, or 2 again (Rock/Paper/Scissor)");
              System.out.println("Computer: " + computerWinCount + " rounds won");
              System.out.println("You: " + humanWinCount + " rounds won");
              choiceRPS = userRPS.nextInt();
            }
          } else if (choiceRPS == 1) {
            if (n == 1) {
              System.out.println("WIN!!");
              System.out.println("Choose 0, 1, or 2 again (Rock/Paper/Scissor)");
              humanWinCount = humanWinCount + 1;
              System.out.println("Computer: " + computerWinCount + " rounds won");
              System.out.println("You: " + humanWinCount + " rounds won");
              choiceRPS = userRPS.nextInt();
            } else if (n == 2) {
              System.out.println("TIE!!");
              System.out.println("Choose 0, 1, or 2 again (Rock/Paper/Scissor)");
              System.out.println("Computer: " + computerWinCount + " rounds won");
              System.out.println("You: " + humanWinCount + " rounds won");
              choiceRPS = userRPS.nextInt();
            } else if (n == 3) {
              System.out.println("LOSS!!");
              System.out.println("Choose 0, 1, or 2 again (Rock/Paper/Scissor)");
              computerWinCount = computerWinCount + 1;
              System.out.println("Computer: " + computerWinCount + " rounds won");
              System.out.println("You: " + humanWinCount + " rounds won");
              choiceRPS = userRPS.nextInt();
            } else {
              System.out.println("I do not understand... Try again.");
              System.out.println("Choose 0, 1, or 2 again (Rock/Paper/Scissor)");
              System.out.println("Computer: " + computerWinCount + " rounds won");
              System.out.println("You: " + humanWinCount + " rounds won");
              choiceRPS = userRPS.nextInt();
            }
          } else if (choiceRPS == 2) {
            if (n == 1) {
              System.out.println("LOSS");
              System.out.println("Choose 0, 1, or 2 again (Rock/Paper/Scissor)");
              computerWinCount = computerWinCount + 1;
              System.out.println("Computer: " + computerWinCount + " rounds won");
              System.out.println("You: " + humanWinCount + " rounds won");
              choiceRPS = userRPS.nextInt();
            } else if (n == 2) {
              System.out.println("WIN!!");
              System.out.println("Choose 0, 1, or 2 again (Rock/Paper/Scissor)");
              humanWinCount = humanWinCount + 1;
              System.out.println("Computer: " + computerWinCount + " rounds won");
              System.out.println("You: " + humanWinCount + " rounds won");
              choiceRPS = userRPS.nextInt();
            } else if (n == 3) {
              System.out.println("TIE!!");
              System.out.println("Choose 0, 1, or 2 again (Rock/Paper/Scissor)");
              System.out.println("Computer: " + computerWinCount + " rounds won");
              System.out.println("You: " + humanWinCount + " rounds won");
              choiceRPS = userRPS.nextInt();
            } else {
              System.out.println("I do not understand... Try again.");
              System.out.println("Choose 0, 1, or 2 again (Rock/Paper/Scissor)");
              System.out.println("Computer: " + computerWinCount + " rounds won");
              System.out.println("You: " + humanWinCount + " rounds won");
              choiceRPS = userRPS.nextInt();
            }
          }
        }

        if (humanWinCount == 5) {
          System.out.println("Congratulations, you win!!");
          System.out.println("Computer: " + computerWinCount + " rounds won");
          System.out.println("You: " + humanWinCount + " rounds won");
          System.out.println("Would you like to try again? (Y/N)");
          Scanner continueOrNot = new Scanner(System.in);
          String contOrNot = continueOrNot.next();
          if (contOrNot.equals("Y")) {
            loopGameStart = true;
          } else if (contOrNot.equals("N")) {
            System.out.println("Okay, goodbye!!");
            loopGameStart = false;
          }
        }

        if (computerWinCount == 5) {
          System.out.println("Boohoo, you lost!!");
          System.out.println("Computer: " + computerWinCount + " rounds won");
          System.out.println("You: " + humanWinCount + " rounds won");
          System.out.println("Would you like to try again? (Y/N)");
          Scanner continueOrNot = new Scanner(System.in);
          String contOrNot = continueOrNot.next();
          if (contOrNot.equals("Y")) {
            loopGameStart = true;
          } else if (contOrNot.equals("N")) {
            System.out.println("Okay, goodbye!!");
            loopGameStart = false;
          }
        }
      } else {
        System.out.println("I do not understand, please try again!");
      }
    }
  }

  public static int humanWinCount() {
      int x = 0;
      return x;
  }

  public static int computerWinCount() {
      int c = 0;
      return c;
  }
}
```

Comment: **P.S.** `humanWinCount()` and `computerWinCount()` will always `return 0`

Comment: You do not need to create multiple scanner objects. Maintain just one. Anyway, since all of them are using "System.in", if you close even one of them, all of them will get closed. So, better to have just one object, use it in the complete program.

Comment: I suggest you extract some (or rather, MOST) of your code to methods so you don't repeat yourself. Also try using constants.

Answer (score 13):

Please, do not write everything in one main function, or repeat the same code everywhere, and etc.

I completely rebuild your code and also implemented the loop [@Austin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7206778) suggested. Now your should be working as you which or very close. Enjoy:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Rock_Paper_Scissors
{
    public static void main( String arg[] )
    {
        Rock_Paper_Scissors game = new Rock_Paper_Scissors();
        game.startLogic();
    }

    private Random  rand;
    private Scanner inputScanner;
    private boolean loopGameStart;

    private int humanWinCount;
    private int computerWinCount;

    public Rock_Paper_Scissors()
    {
        this.rand          = new Random();
        this.inputScanner  = new Scanner( System.in );
        this.loopGameStart = true;

        humanWinCount    = 0;
        computerWinCount = 0;
    }

    public void startLogic()
    {
        System.out.print( "Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors, a game programmed by Daniel Park. " );
        this.askUntilGetAnAnswer( "N" );
    }

    private int humanWinCount()
    {
        int x = 0;
        return x;
    }

    private int computerWinCount()
    {
        int c = 0;
        return c;
    }

    private void askUntilGetAnAnswer( String determination )
    {
        while( this.loopGameStart )
        {
            if( !determination.equals( "Y" ) )
            {
                System.out.println( "\nWould you like to start? (Y/N)" );
                determination = this.inputScanner.next();
            }

            if( determination.equals( "N" ) )
            {
                System.out.println( "Please, do reconsider..." );
                this.loopGameStart = false;
            }
            else if( determination.equals( "Y" ) )
            {
                this.processCoreGameLogic();
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print( "I do not understand, please try again!" );
            }
        }
    }

    private void processCoreGameLogic()
    {
        int choiceRPS;
        System.out.println( "Choose 0, 1, or 2 (Rock/Paper/Scissor)" );

        // 1 = Rock, 2 = Paper, 3= Scissor
        this.humanWinCount    = this.humanWinCount();
        this.computerWinCount = this.computerWinCount();

        while( ( this.humanWinCount < 5 ) && ( this.computerWinCount < 5 ) )
        {
            try
            {
                choiceRPS = inputScanner.nextInt();

                if( choiceRPS >= 0 && choiceRPS <= 2 )
                {
                    this.playing( choiceRPS );
                }
            }
            catch( InputMismatchException e )
            {
                System.out.print( "I do not understand, please try again!" );
                inputScanner.next();
            } 

        }

        this.endGame();
    }

    private void endGame()
    {
        String contOrNot = "";

        if( this.humanWinCount == 5 )
        {
            System.out.println( "\nCongratulations, you win!!" );
            System.out.println( "Computer: " + this.computerWinCount + " rounds won" );
            System.out.println( "You: " + this.humanWinCount + " rounds won" );
            System.out.println( "Would you like to try again? (Y/N)" );

            contOrNot = this.inputScanner.next();
        }

        if( this.computerWinCount == 5 )
        {
            System.out.println( "\nBoohoo, you lost!!" );
            System.out.println( "Computer: " + this.computerWinCount + " rounds won" );
            System.out.println( "You: " + this.humanWinCount + " rounds won" );
            System.out.println( "Would you like to try again? (Y/N)" );

            contOrNot = this.inputScanner.next();
        }

        if( contOrNot.equals( "N" ) )
        {
            System.out.println( "Okay, goodbye!!" );
            this.loopGameStart = false;
        }
        else
        {
            askUntilGetAnAnswer( contOrNot );
        }
    }

    private void playing( int choiceRPS )
    {
        int randomInteger = this.rand.nextInt( 3 ) + 1;

        // choiceRPS 0 -> tie  1, loss 2, win  3
        // choiceRPS 1 -> win  3, tie  1, loss 2
        // choiceRPS 2 -> loss 2, win  3, tie  1
        //
        switch( choiceRPS*3 + randomInteger )
        {
            case 1:
            case 5:
            case 9:
            {
                show_tie();
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            case 6:
            case 7:
            {
                show_loss();
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            case 4:
            case 8:
            {
                show_win();
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                System.out.println( "    I do not understand... Try again." );
                System.out.println( "    Choose 0, 1, or 2 again (Rock/Paper/Scissor)" );
                System.out.println( "    Computer: " + this.computerWinCount + " rounds won" );
                System.out.println( "    You: " + this.humanWinCount + " rounds won" );
            }
        }
    }

    private void show_loss()
    {
        System.out.println( "LOSS" );
        System.out.println( "Choose 0, 1, or 2 again (Rock/Paper/Scissor)" );
        this.computerWinCount = this.computerWinCount + 1;
        System.out.println( "Computer: " + this.computerWinCount + " rounds won" );
        System.out.println( "You: " + this.humanWinCount + " rounds won" );
    }

    private void show_win()
    {
        System.out.println( "WIN!!" );
        System.out.println( "Choose 0, 1, or 2 again (Rock/Paper/Scissor)" );
        this.humanWinCount = this.humanWinCount + 1;
        System.out.println( "Computer: " + this.computerWinCount + " rounds won" );
        System.out.println( "You: " + this.humanWinCount + " rounds won" );
    }

    private void show_tie()
    {
        System.out.println( "TIE!!" );
        System.out.println( "Choose 0, 1, or 2 again (Rock/Paper/Scissor)" );
        System.out.println( "Computer: " + this.computerWinCount + " rounds won" );
        System.out.println( "You: " + this.humanWinCount + " rounds won" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much. I was thinking about trying to rewrite this code anyways, because of the exact issue you brought up. I'm still learning java, and even I saw how redundant the code became :/

Comment: Although its nice of you to rewrite the whole program, I don't think this is the goal of stackoverflow. I do not think, that Perambulation learns a lot of this answer...

Answer (score 7):

You can use a do while

```
int choiceRPS;
 do{
    choiceRPS = userRPS.nextInt();
}while(choiceRPS<0||choiceRPS>2);
```

Comment: So, how would that look like in my code? Would I move everything I did after int choiceRPS = userRPS.nextInt(); over?

Comment: when you use a do while every thing in the do will run at least once and if the conditions of the while aren't met so if I entered 3  the loop would run again only the code in the do while needs to be indented

Comment: Now that I've done that, the code gives me an error as choiceRPS's value is now out of the scope...

Comment: I fixed it choiceRPS just needed to be initialized outside of the loop.

Comment: @Perambulation check the condition. This is clearly the easiest solution here. Basicly, ask an input if the value is `< 0 or > 2` (and ask at least once)

Comment: The nextInt() Method of Scanner throws an InputMismatchException if you input characters like a. You must capture the Exception and call Scanner.next() to consume the (wrong) input from Scanner to prevent an endless loop!

Answer (score 5):

Your logic looks very complex. It can be easily simplified as the game has only 3 outcomes other that a **tie**.

> SCISSORS beats PAPER
>
> PAPER beats ROCK
>
> ROCK beats SCISSORS

So considering the inputs as 0, 1 and 2 representing Rock, Paper and Scissors respectively:

1. You need to keep track of two numbers. One is user entered choice
   let's call it `userChoice` and another being `computerChoice` which
   is computer's played choice. This `computerChoice` should be a
   randomly chosen digit between 0 and 2 both inclusive.
2. Now, start comparing both the numbers to decide on the winner and
   increment the respective counter (`humanWinCount` and
   `computerWinCount`).
3. Stop the game and decide the winner when either the user or the
   computer wins at least 5 rounds.

Hence, your gaming loop should be looking something like this:

```
while(true){
            System.out.println();
            /*
             * If either one wins, break out of the game
             * and decide the winner.
             */
            if(humanWinCount == 5 || computerWinCount == 5){
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("Choose 0, 1, or 2 (Rock/Paper/Scissor)");
            //Read user's choice
            int userChoice = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
            //Computer will play it's turn
            int computerChoice = rand.nextInt(3);

            //Start comparing player's choice vs Computer's choice
            if(userChoice == computerChoice){
                tieCount++;
                showTieMessage();
            }else if(userChoice == 0 && computerChoice == 1){
                //User plays ROCK and computer plays PAPER 
                computerWinCount++;
                showComputerWinMessage();
            }else if(userChoice == 0 && computerChoice == 2){
                //User plays ROCK and computer plays SCISSORS
                humanWinCount++;
                showHumanWinMessage();
            }else if(userChoice == 1 && computerChoice == 0){
                //User plays PAPER and computer plays ROCK
                humanWinCount++;
                showHumanWinMessage();
            }else if(userChoice == 1 && computerChoice == 2){
                //User plays PAPER and computer plays SCISSORS 
                computerWinCount++;
                showComputerWinMessage();
            }else if(userChoice == 2 && computerChoice == 0){
                //User plays SCISSORS and computer plays ROCK
                computerWinCount++;
                showComputerWinMessage();
            }else if(userChoice == 2 && computerChoice == 1){
                //User plays SCISSORS and computer plays PAPER
                humanWinCount++;
                showHumanWinMessage();
            }else{
                System.out.println("Unrecougnized user input!!");
                System.out.println("Please Enter correct values!!");
                continue;
            }
        }
```

And the entire remodeled code should be looking something like this:

```
public class RockPepperScissor {
    private Random rand;
    private int humanWinCount;
    private int computerWinCount;
    private int tieCount; //Not Required, but still keeping in track.

    public RockPepperScissor(){
        rand = new Random();
        humanWinCount = 0;
        computerWinCount = 0;
        tieCount = 0;
    }

    public void startGame(){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors, a game programmed by Daniel Park. Would you like to start? (Y/N)");
        String userChoice = sc.nextLine();
        if(userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")){
            startGameLogic(sc);
        }else{
            if(userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("N")){
                System.out.println("Do you want to reconsider?? (Y/N)");
                String secondChance = sc.nextLine();
                if(secondChance.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")){
                    startGameLogic(sc);
                }else{
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }else{
                System.out.println("Unable to identify your input!! Stopping the game!!");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        sc.close();
    }

    public void startGameLogic(Scanner sc){
        while(true){
            System.out.println();
            /*
             * If either one wins, break out of the game
             * and decide the winner.
             */
            if(humanWinCount == 5 || computerWinCount == 5){
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("Choose 0, 1, or 2 (Rock/Paper/Scissor)");
            //Read user's choice
            int userChoice = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
            //Computer will play it's turn
            int computerChoice = rand.nextInt(3);

            //Start comparing player's choice vs Computer's choice
            if(userChoice == computerChoice){
                tieCount++;
                showTieMessage();
            }else if(userChoice == 0 && computerChoice == 1){
                //User plays ROCK and computer plays PAPER 
                computerWinCount++;
                showComputerWinMessage();
            }else if(userChoice == 0 && computerChoice == 2){
                //User plays ROCK and computer plays SCISSORS
                humanWinCount++;
                showHumanWinMessage();
            }else if(userChoice == 1 && computerChoice == 0){
                //User plays PAPER and computer plays ROCK
                humanWinCount++;
                showHumanWinMessage();
            }else if(userChoice == 1 && computerChoice == 2){
                //User plays PAPER and computer plays SCISSORS 
                computerWinCount++;
                showComputerWinMessage();
            }else if(userChoice == 2 && computerChoice == 0){
                //User plays SCISSORS and computer plays ROCK
                computerWinCount++;
                showComputerWinMessage();
            }else if(userChoice == 2 && computerChoice == 1){
                //User plays SCISSORS and computer plays PAPER
                humanWinCount++;
                showHumanWinMessage();
            }else{
                System.out.println("Unrecougnized user input!!");
                System.out.println("Please Enter correct values!!");
                continue;
            }
        }

    }

    public void showHumanWinMessage(){
        System.out.println("YOU WON!!");
        System.out.println("Your wins: " + humanWinCount);
        System.out.println("Computer wins: " + computerWinCount);
        System.out.println("Ties: " + tieCount);
    }

    public void showComputerWinMessage(){
        System.out.println("YOU LOST!!");
        System.out.println("Your wins: " + humanWinCount);
        System.out.println("Computer wins: " + computerWinCount);
        System.out.println("Ties: " + tieCount);
    }

    public void showTieMessage(){
        System.out.println("Tie!!");
        System.out.println("Your wins: " + humanWinCount);
        System.out.println("Computer wins: " + computerWinCount);
        System.out.println("Ties: " + tieCount);
    }

    public void decideWinner(){
        if(humanWinCount > computerWinCount){
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Yippee!! You won the Game!!");
        }else if(computerWinCount > humanWinCount){
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Oops!! You lost the Game!!");
            System.out.println("Better Luck Next Time!!");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RockPepperScissor rps = new RockPepperScissor();
        rps.startGame();
        rps.decideWinner();
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you in your learning activity.

Answer (score 3):

So it's pretty much visible that the code is not modular and there are redundant statements in the code. They might still be there, since all I did was to fix the logic and make comments on the code for the changes introduced  -

```
public class Rock_Paper_Scissors {

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        boolean loopGameStart = true;
        while (loopGameStart) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors, a game programmed by Daniel Park. Would you like to start? (Y/N)");
            Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
            String determination = userInput.next();

            switch (determination) {
                case "N":
                    System.out.println("Please, do reconsider...");
                    loopGameStart = true; // you might not want the player to be trapped here, so change it to `false` rather
                    break;
                case "Y":
                    /** 0 = Rock, 1 = Paper, 2 = Scissor */
                    int humanWinCount = 0;
                    int computerWinCount = 0;

                    System.out.println("Choose 0, 1, or 2 (Rock/Paper/Scissor)");
                    Scanner userRPS = new Scanner(System.in);
                    int userChoice = userRPS.nextInt();

                    while ((humanWinCount < 5) && (computerWinCount < 5)) { // either of them reaches 5
                        int computerChoice = new Random().nextInt(3); // this is fun, no more static computer choice
                        if (userChoice == computerChoice) { // break quick if its a tie
                            System.out.println("TIE!!");
                            displayStats(computerWinCount, humanWinCount);
                            askChoice();
                        } else {
                            switch (userChoice) { //based on userChoice and computerChoice combination
                                case 0:
                                    if (computerChoice == 1) {
                                        System.out.println("LOSS!!");
                                        displayStats(computerWinCount++,
                                                humanWinCount); // incrementing the computerCount as well
                                        askChoice();
                                    } else if (computerChoice == 2) {
                                        System.out.println("WIN!!");
                                        displayStats(computerWinCount,
                                                humanWinCount++); // incrementing the humanCount as well
                                        askChoice();
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case 1:
                                    if (computerChoice == 0) {
                                        System.out.println("WIN!!");
                                        displayStats(computerWinCount, humanWinCount++);
                                        askChoice();
                                    } else if (computerChoice == 2) {
                                        System.out.println("LOSS!!");
                                        displayStats(computerWinCount++, humanWinCount);
                                        askChoice();
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    if (computerChoice == 0) {
                                        System.out.println("LOSS");
                                        displayStats(computerWinCount++, humanWinCount);
                                        askChoice();
                                    } else if (computerChoice == 1) {
                                        System.out.println("WIN!!");
                                        displayStats(computerWinCount, humanWinCount++);
                                        askChoice();
                                    }
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    System.out.println("I do not understand... Try again.");
                                    displayStats(computerWinCount, humanWinCount);
                                    askChoice();
                                    break;

                            }
                        }

                        userChoice = userRPS.nextInt(); //next iteration input only required once
                    }

                    if (humanWinCount == 5) {
                        System.out.println("Congratulations, you win!!");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Boohoo, you lost!!");
                    }
                    displayStats(computerWinCount, humanWinCount);
                    System.out.println("Would you like to try again? (Y/N)");
                    Scanner continueOrNot = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String contOrNot = continueOrNot.next();
                    if (contOrNot.equals("Y")) {
                        loopGameStart = true;
                    } else if (contOrNot.equals("N")) {
                        System.out.println("Okay, goodbye!!");
                        loopGameStart = false;
                    }
                    break;


                default:
                    System.out.println("I do not understand, please try again!");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void askChoice() {
        System.out.println("Choose 0, 1, or 2 again (Rock/Paper/Scissor)");
    }

    private static void displayStats(int computerWinCount, int humanWinCount) {
        System.out.println("Computer: " + computerWinCount + " rounds won");
        System.out.println("You: " + humanWinCount + " rounds won");
    }
}
```

The code explanation would be something that I would leave on what you won't understand in it. So please ask further for anything that you might want to know about *why it's being used.*

Answer (score 2):

If you need to loop certain code with conditional behaviour, try to use recursive parametric method and enclapsure the conditional parts code each into separate method. These methods will be called from the current recursion. Then call first-time recursion level from `main` method.

Pseudo-sample:

```
public int myRecursiveMethod_RPS (int aVariable)
{
  System.out.println("Choose 0, 1, or 2 (Rock/Paper/Scissor)");
  ...
  // your own logic below - this is just sample
  if (aVariable == 0) 
    return myRecursiveMethod_RPS(0);
  else if (aVariable >= 0) 
    return myRecursiveMethod_RPS(aVariable);
  else return aVariable;
}
```

Good article about recursion is here [Recursion - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23347681/recursion-java) or 
here https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/java-recursion/

Answer (score 2):

Try using a do/while loop. The code is run until a certain condition is no longer met, but at least it will be run once even if the condition is not true at the beginning. Using your first input as an example, it would look just like this:

```
String determination; // I move the variable determination outside so it is in the scope of the while.

do {
System.out.println(
                    "Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors, a game programmed by Daniel Park. Would you like to start? (Y/N)");
            Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
            determination = userInput.next();
} while (determination != "Y" || determination != "N");
//...
```

The code will at least be run once. If at anytime 'determination' equals "N" or "Y", it will go on with the rest of the code.

You can get more information from this website:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Answer (score 1):

As i already edited into addons_zz modular version of your program Perambulation: The Scanner that is used for userinput throws an InputMismatchException if you input e.g. "a" and the nextInt() Method of the Scanner is called. The Input "a" can't be cast to the type integer since its a character of the alphabet. A solution to this could look like(in your version of the code):

```
...
} else if (determination.equals("Y")) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int n = rand.nextInt(3) + 1;
    // 1 = Rock, 2 = Paper, 3= Scissor
    int humanWinCount = humanWinCount();
    int computerWinCount = computerWinCount();
    Scanner userRPS = new Scanner(System.in);

    // loop until choiceRPS is 0, 1 or 2
    int choiceRPS = 9;
    boolean choiceRPSNotSet = true;
    while(choiceRPSNotSet){

        System.out.println("Choose 0, 1, or 2 (Rock/Paper/Scissor)");

        try
        {
            choiceRPS = userRPS.nextInt();

            if( choiceRPS >= 0 && choiceRPS <= 2 )
            {
                choiceRPSNotSet = false;
            }
        }
        catch( InputMismatchException e )
        {
            System.out.println( "I do not understand, please try again!" );
            userRPS.next();
        } 
    }
    // loop until choiceRPS is 0, 1 or 2

    while ((humanWinCount < 5) && (computerWinCount < 5)) {
    ...
```

So i added another while loop based on the condition that choiceRPS is set correctly.

```
if( choiceRPS >= 0 && choiceRPS <= 2 )
        {
            choiceRPSNotSet = false;
        }
```

Only then the loop will be left which includes catching Exceptions since this part is located in the try/catch block.

Calling the userRPS.next() (or Scanner.next()) Method if an InputMismatchException occurs will clean the Input from the Scanner so that a new input can be read.

An alternative which i would recommend would be encapsulating the userinput into its own method like:

```
public static int choose(){
    Scanner userRPS = new Scanner(System.in);
    // loop until choiceRPS is 0, 1 or 2
    int choiceRPS = 9;
    boolean choiceRPSNotSet = true;
    while(choiceRPSNotSet){

        System.out.println("Choose 0, 1, or 2 (Rock/Paper/Scissor)");

        try
        {
            choiceRPS = userRPS.nextInt();

            if( choiceRPS >= 0 && choiceRPS <= 2 )
            {
                choiceRPSNotSet = false;
            }
        }
        catch( InputMismatchException e )
        {
            System.out.println( "I do not understand, please try again!" );
            userRPS.next();
        } 
    }
    // loop until choiceRPS is 0, 1 or 2
    return choiceRPS;
}
```

And calling this choose() method whenever necessary like:

```
...
} else if (determination.equals("Y")) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int n = rand.nextInt(3) + 1;
        // 1 = Rock, 2 = Paper, 3= Scissor
        int humanWinCount = humanWinCount();
        int computerWinCount = computerWinCount();


        int choiceRPS = choose();

    while ((humanWinCount < 5) && (computerWinCount < 5)) {
      if (choiceRPS == 0) {
        if (n == 1) {
          System.out.println("TIE!!");
          System.out.println("Choose 0, 1, or 2 again (Rock/Paper/Scissor)");
          System.out.println("Computer: " + computerWinCount + " rounds won");
          System.out.println("You: " + humanWinCount + " rounds won");

          choiceRPS = choose();

        } else if (n == 2) {
          System.out.println("LOSS!!");
          System.out.println("Choose 0, 1, or 2 again (Rock/Paper/Scissor)");
          computerWinCount = computerWinCount + 1;
          System.out.println("Computer: " + computerWinCount + " rounds won");
          System.out.println("You: " + humanWinCount + " rounds won");

          choiceRPS = choose();
...
```

Hope this helps! ^^

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Rock_Paper_Scissors {

  public static void main(String arg[]) {
    boolean loopGameStart = true;

    while (loopGameStart) {
      System.out.println("Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors, a game programmed "
                       + "by Daniel Park. Would you like to start? (Y/N)");
      Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
      String determination = userInput.next();
      //1=THIS CHANGED TO IGNORE CASE N or n Y or y accepted
      if (determination.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
        System.out.println("Please, do reconsider...");
        loopGameStart = true;
      } else if (determination.equals("Y")) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int n = rand.nextInt(3) + 1;
        // 1 = Rock, 2 = Paper, 3= Scissor
        int humanWinCount = humanWinCount();
        int computerWinCount = computerWinCount();
        System.out.println("Choose 0, 1, or 2 (Rock/Paper/Scissor)");
        Scanner userRPS = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choiceRPS = userRPS.nextInt();
        while ((humanWinCount < 5) && (computerWinCount < 5)) {
          if (choiceRPS == 0) {
            if (n == 1) {
              System.out.println("TIE!!");
              System.out.println("Choose 0, 1, or 2 again (Rock/Paper/Scissor)");
              System.out.println("Computer: " + computerWinCount + " rounds won");
              System.out.println("You: " + humanWinCount + " rounds won");
              choiceRPS = userRPS.nextInt();
            } else if (n == 2) {
              System.out.println("LOSS!!");
              System.out.println("Choose 0, 1, or 2 again (Rock/Paper/Scissor)");
              computerWinCount = computerWinCount + 1;
              System.out.println("Computer: " + computerWinCount + " rounds won");
              System.out.println("You: " + humanWinCount + " rounds won");
              choiceRPS = userRPS.nextInt();
            } else if (n == 3) {
              System.out.println("WIN!!");
              System.out.println("Choose 0, 1, or 2 again (Rock/Paper/Scissor)");
              humanWinCount = humanWinCount + 1;
              System.out.println("Computer: " + computerWinCount + " rounds won");
              System.out.println("You: " + humanWinCount + " rounds won");
              choiceRPS = userRPS.nextInt();
            } else {
              System.out.println("I do not understand... Try Again.");
              System.out.println("Choose 0, 1, or 2 again (Rock/Paper/Scissor)");
              System.out.println("Computer: " + computerWinCount + " rounds won");
              System.out.println("You: " + humanWinCount + " rounds won");
              choiceRPS = userRPS.nextInt();
            }
          } else if (choiceRPS == 1) {
            if (n == 1) {
              System.out.println("WIN!!");
              System.out.println("Choose 0, 1, or 2 again (Rock/Paper/Scissor)");
              humanWinCount = humanWinCount + 1;
              System.out.println("Computer: " + computerWinCount + " rounds won");
              System.out.println("You: " + humanWinCount + " rounds won");
              choiceRPS = userRPS.nextInt();
            } else if (n == 2) {
              System.out.println("TIE!!");
              System.out.println("Choose 0, 1, or 2 again (Rock/Paper/Scissor)");
              System.out.println("Computer: " + computerWinCount + " rounds won");
              System.out.println("You: " + humanWinCount + " rounds won");
              choiceRPS = userRPS.nextInt();
            } else if (n == 3) {
              System.out.println("LOSS!!");
              System.out.println("Choose 0, 1, or 2 again (Rock/Paper/Scissor)");
              computerWinCount = computerWinCount + 1;
              System.out.println("Computer: " + computerWinCount + " rounds won");
              System.out.println("You: " + humanWinCount + " rounds won");
              choiceRPS = userRPS.nextInt();
            } else {
              System.out.println("I do not understand... Try again.");
              System.out.println("Choose 0, 1, or 2 again (Rock/Paper/Scissor)");
              System.out.println("Computer: " + computerWinCount + " rounds won");
              System.out.println("You: " + humanWinCount + " rounds won");
              choiceRPS = userRPS.nextInt();
            }
          } else if (choiceRPS == 2) {
            if (n == 1) {
              System.out.println("LOSS");
              System.out.println("Choose 0, 1, or 2 again (Rock/Paper/Scissor)");
              computerWinCount = computerWinCount + 1;
              System.out.println("Computer: " + computerWinCount + " rounds won");
              System.out.println("You: " + humanWinCount + " rounds won");
              choiceRPS = userRPS.nextInt();
            } else if (n == 2) {
              System.out.println("WIN!!");
              System.out.println("Choose 0, 1, or 2 again (Rock/Paper/Scissor)");
              humanWinCount = humanWinCount + 1;
              System.out.println("Computer: " + computerWinCount + " rounds won");
              System.out.println("You: " + humanWinCount + " rounds won");
              choiceRPS = userRPS.nextInt();
            } else if (n == 3) {
              System.out.println("TIE!!");
              System.out.println("Choose 0, 1, or 2 again (Rock/Paper/Scissor)");
              System.out.println("Computer: " + computerWinCount + " rounds won");
              System.out.println("You: " + humanWinCount + " rounds won");
              choiceRPS = userRPS.nextInt();
            } else {
              System.out.println("I do not understand... Try again.");
              System.out.println("Choose 0, 1, or 2 again (Rock/Paper/Scissor)");
              System.out.println("Computer: " + computerWinCount + " rounds won");
              System.out.println("You: " + humanWinCount + " rounds won");
              choiceRPS = userRPS.nextInt();
            }
          }else{
              //###################################THIS IS THE ADDED CODE
              System.out.println("INVALID VALUE ENTER AGAIN");
              System.out.println("Choose 0, 1, or 2 again (Rock/Paper/Scissor)");
              System.out.println("Computer: " + computerWinCount + " rounds won");
              System.out.println("You: " + humanWinCount + " rounds won");
              choiceRPS = userRPS.nextInt();
          }
        }

        if (humanWinCount == 5) {
          System.out.println("Congratulations, you win!!");
          System.out.println("Computer: " + computerWinCount + " rounds won");
          System.out.println("You: " + humanWinCount + " rounds won");
          System.out.println("Would you like to try again? (Y/N)");
          Scanner continueOrNot = new Scanner(System.in);
          String contOrNot = continueOrNot.next();
          if (contOrNot.equals("Y")) {
            loopGameStart = true;
          } else if (contOrNot.equals("N")) {
            System.out.println("Okay, goodbye!!");
            loopGameStart = false;
          }
        }

        if (computerWinCount == 5) {
          System.out.println("Boohoo, you lost!!");
          System.out.println("Computer: " + computerWinCount + " rounds won");
          System.out.println("You: " + humanWinCount + " rounds won");
          System.out.println("Would you like to try again? (Y/N)");
          Scanner continueOrNot = new Scanner(System.in);
          String contOrNot = continueOrNot.next();
          if (contOrNot.equals("Y")) {
            loopGameStart = true;
          } else if (contOrNot.equals("N")) {
            System.out.println("Okay, goodbye!!");
            loopGameStart = false;
          }
        }
      } else {
        System.out.println("I do not understand, please try again!");
      }
    }


    }
      public static int humanWinCount() {
          int x = 0;
          return x;
      }

      public static int computerWinCount() {
          int c = 0;
          return c;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a simple loop would do the trick :

```
Scanner answerScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
do{
  char answer = answerScanner.next().charAt(0);
}while(answer != 'Y' && answer != 'N');

// Then do whatever you need to do
if(answer == 'Y'){
  // Something
}else{
  // Something else
}
```

Note that you could use answerScanner.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0) if you wanted to allow 'y' and 'n' as answers.